# The name of $fusc$ (Calkin-Wilf sequence)

Tags: terminology, math-history

I was just wondering where $fusc$ got its name (where $fusc(2n) = fusc(n), fusc(2n + 1) = fusc(n) + fusc(n + 1)$, seeds: $fusc(0) = 0, fusc(1) = 1$). The function is of some importance in the Calkin-Wilf sequence and is interesting in its own right.

Comment: The best that I have been able to find so far is EWD570: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD05xx/EWD570.html . Dijkstra named it, apparently while toying around during a national holiday on or before 27 May A.D. 1976, but does not seem to give any indications as to how he chose the name (it may have been completely random/arbitrary).

Comment: A follow up article by the same EWD: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD05xx/EWD578.html

Comment: Dijkstra writes: "The function $fusc$ is of a mild interest on account of the following property: [...] In the above recursive definition, this is no longer obvious, at least not to me; hence its name."  That suggests to me that that the function draws its name from the word [*obfuscated*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate).

Comment: Though now I wish some Oxford-educated combinatorist would come up with a sequence dominated by $fusc$, and name it [$subfusc$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_dress_of_the_University_of_Oxford#Subfusc).